# Custom title bar with ListView

Tags: android

I have a Activity Extend ListActivity
I want add a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout on top of the list
like a action title
But when I add in XML
List not Display,Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<RelativeLayout
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="1111" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"/>  
</RelativeLayout>
    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:padding="4dip" />
    <TextView android:id="@id/android:empty" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:text="No_data" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your RelativeLayout above the list has a height of fill_parent and leaves no space left for the list below it. Try setting a different value for layout_height on the RelativeLayout, either a constant height in dips or wrap_content.

You also want orientation="vertical" on your root LinearLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Jason,

Google has provided a good example of what you call an "action title" here: http://code.google.com/p/iosched/

Full source code is provided.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have extended ListActivity. You need to extend just a normal Activity and use a ListView instead of ListActivity.

Refer the link [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html)

Here is the text that you need

> ListActivity has a default layout that
>   consists of a single, full-screen list
>   in the center of the screen. However,
>   if you desire, you can customize the
>   screen layout by setting your own view
>   layout with setContentView() in
>   onCreate(). To do this, your own view
>   MUST contain a ListView object with
>   the id "@android:id/list" (or list if
>   it's in code)

Comment: There is nothing stopping him from using ListActivity here, the layout is wrong and leaves no space for the ListView.

Comment: No problem. :) This is a fairly common issue, and it's why we changed the name of "fill_parent" to "match_parent" a few versions ago. "fill_parent" implied a behavior similar to layout_weight to a lot of people where space would be shared with later elements, but it really means, "take the rest of the available space in this direction." Once you have a match_parent item in a LinearLayout going in the same direction, all subsequent children will be measured with a width or height of 0 since there's no space left to give them.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem, where nothing showed up. The problem for me was that Android wasn't re-inflating resource properly. Adding the second line here fixed it for me:

```
final boolean useCustomTitle=requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
getWindow().getDecorView();//required to make title show up
if(useCustomTitle)
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.my_custom_title);
```

The second line returns a view, but I don't need it. However, the code will not work without it. You can find the Android source code online if you need to find workarounds.
The `private TextView mTitleView` still isn't updated, so you can either override setTitle or use reflection.